# How do I view and delete Kafka topics

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

I tried deleting all logs at `/var/lib/kafka` I do get fresh messages but I don't feel this is the correct way. I've already set `delete.topic.enable=true` at `/etc/kafka/server.properties` P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To view Kafka topics** :

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper host:2181 --list
```

**To delete a Kafka topic** :

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper host:2181 --delete --topic topic_name
```

> To find kafka-topics try this : `locate -i kafka-topics.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I think one good way is to use some graphic user interface tools, like kafka-manager(https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way so far is to invoke `kafka-topics.sh --delete.....` with `delete.topic.enable` set to true.

Comment: I'm using Kafka by Confluent, so may I know where do I find `kafka-topics.sh` ? I tried looking for it using the `find` command but couldn't get any result.

Comment: `locate -i kafka-topics.sh` ?

Comment: @KelvinLowEeHahn It is located under bin/ .